# How do I create a self-defined ciphersuite and use it by setEnabledCipherSuites(_)?

Tags: java, bouncycastle, tls1.2

I am trying to write a self-defined ciphersuite and use it for tls connection, how can this be implemented?

Comment: Whatever you do will have to be done at both ends.

Answer (score -1):

SSLSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites() uses the built in implementation cipher suites, so you would have to modify the javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket class to support your custom suite, which may be more than you want to do.

Comment: Not so. You would age to add your implementation via JCA.